# Change two array values in one row (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of two elements

```
q = [0, 0]
```

The values of the elements change during code execution in the following form:

```
q[0] += hereHumber
q[1] += 1
```

Is it possible to change elements in one line? Maybe with Numpy? how? :))))

Comment: yes,it is., GIYF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You can pass one value that will be added to all, or a same'size list and it'll be added element-wise

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 0])
print(a)  # [0 0]

a += 2
print(a)  # [2 2]

a += [2, 4]
print(a)  # [4 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with default python list comprehension.

```
q = [0, 0]
q = [q[enum[0]] + num for enum, num in zip(enumerate(q), [here_number, 1])]
```

But numpy-way is better.

Comment: the answer you are arguing can be supplemented with more information please add more information by editing and also read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)